# How to reset password for all users in csv from prompt and code cleanup

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working on setting up an automated script that will reset the users passwords in the csv, enable their accounts, and force them to change their passwords at logon. I'm new to scripting with `PowerShell`. Any way I can make this simpler as well would be awesome. I feel like I don't need `Get-AdUser` multiple times and I should be able to pipe everything with one line right?

I'm trying to keep myself from being prompted for each individual user password reset.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$newPassword = $(Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString)
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\ADUsers.csv" | ForEach-Object {
 $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADAccountPassword $newPassword
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Enable-ADAccount
Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True
}
```

Error I'm receiving:

> Set-ADAccountPassword : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot
>   convert the  "System.Security.SecureString" value of type
>   "System.Security.SecureString" to type 
>   "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount". At line:5 char:62
>   + ... ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADAccountPassword $newPassword
>   +                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADAccountPassword], ParameterBindi     ngException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Man
>   agement.Commands.SetADAccountPassword

**edit** Does this look right? I guess I missed the -NewPassword tag in the original script.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $newPassword
```

I did get a different return this time. I'll have to try it out on the DC tomorrow.

Can I also not just pipe these two together like so?

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $newPassword | Enable-ADAccount
```

Comment: have you looked at the help for that cmdlet? are you sending the correct object type to it via the pipeline? what happens if you do the sensible thing and use the correct parameter name for the new password? [*grin*]

Comment: Does this look right? I guess I missed the -NewPassword tag

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $newPassword
```


I did get a different return this time. I'll have to try it out on the DC tomorrow.

Comment: i don't have access to any of the AD stuff, so i'm just reading the docs. [*grin*] the next thing i would check would be just what is being sent across the pipe. cmdlets that accept pipeline input usually have some sort of requirement - "ByValue` or `ByName`. if the stuff being passed across the pipe has no identity property, then your code may need to be restructured somehow to give the cmdlet the property it needs with the name and value it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set-ADAccountPassword : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot
>   convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type
>   "System.Security.SecureString" to type
>   "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount". At line:5 char:62 +
>   ... ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADAccountPassword
>   $newPassword + ~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:)
>   [Set-ADAccountPassword], ParameterBindi ngException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Man
>   agement.Commands.SetADAccountPassword

The error above presented itself because you were piping an `ADUser` object into a `Set-AdAccountPassword` without any named parameters. The `-Identity` parameter is the only parameter that takes a value by pipeline and is set for position 0. As a result, `$newPassword` will be bound to `-Identity` (since it is the first argument, aka position 0) and nothing from the pipeline will be bound to anything. Adding the `-NewPassword` frees up `-Identity` for a pipeline input.

---

> Can I also not just pipe these two together like so?
>
> ```
> Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADAccountPassword
> -NewPassword $newPassword | Enable-ADAccount
> ```

Running the code exactly as you have listed will not perform the action you require. By default, `Set-ADAccountPassword` outputs nothing; so nothing will enter the pipeline for the last command. However, hope is not completely lost since `Set-AdAccountPassword` offers the `-PassThru` switch, which will output the current item you are using. Also, if the account has a password set already, you will need to include the `-Reset` switch. Otherwise, you will be required to provide the current password before changing it. If anything has a chance to work, it will be the following:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName |
    Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $newPassword -PassThru -Reset | Enable-ADAccount
```

Comment: Hi AdminOfThings. I was indeed missing -NewPassword and I appreciate the way you explained that to me. Everything seems to be working fine. I did not end up piping the Enable-ADAccount with -PassThru and kept it as 3 lines. Thank you!